# Push notification in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I asking this question for clarification about push notification in xamarin. I have a xamarin.forms app which will display certain items in list view.The back-end of my app is in .Net. The items which shows in list view inside app is added from back-end.What I am trying to achieve is whenever items add in back-end, I want to receive notification in my app.

For the notification part I found two options.

1. **FirebasePlugin**  [Link](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin)
2. **Azure push notification**

I need some clarifications about

1. Which way should I follow? Is there any other cost effective way to implement push notifications in ios and android in cross platform way(Xamarin.forms)?
2. For implementing push notifications in ios ,is APN certificate is mandatory? Currently I don't have apple developer account.So for testing notification in ios seems difficult.
   Any help or guidance is appreciated

Comment: Hi , if answer be helpful , remember to mark it when have time :)

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Hi I little bit confused now. One answer suggest to use firebase and another one suggest app center.

Comment: Okey , it depends on you . You can discuss with your team members to decide which one to choose .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Which way should I follow? Is there any other cost effective way to implement push notifications in ios and android in cross platform way(Xamarin.forms)?

From my experience the easiest way for me was to use firebase console to manage notifications both for Android and iOS. I have similar platform that uses push notifications to users whenever webapp database is updated, by certain users. To my disappointment Azure Push were more complicated to manage.

2. For implementing push notifications in ios ,is APN certificate is mandatory? Currently I don't have apple developer account.So for testing notification in ios seems difficult. Any help or guidance is appreciated

Yes. Apple developer account is mandatory. Moreover you cannot test your push notifications on iOS emulator. You must use physical device.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. For firebase notification is there any cross platform way other than the mentioned plugin?

Comment: I tied this plugin some time ago and it was already outdated. I am not using it. I have implemented my own methods both for Android and iOS - its quite easy with libs provided by MS and Google. I would say don't relay to much on third party plugins if you are developing business application.

Comment: okey, Can you share some thoughts about how to implement firebase notification on ios and android. like some links etc. It will be really helpfull

Comment: for iOS: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging/4.1.1.1?_src=template, for Android https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging/71.1740.0?_src=template

Answer (score 1):

[App Center Push](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/push/) is what I've started using now. Push services are free (which is great) and they have [Xamarin SDKs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/push/xamarin-forms) which handle most of the platform specific config so it's really quick to get push working.

As the other answer has stated, you will still need an apple developer account and physical device to test on iOS.

It's part of the the Microsoft App Center offering which provides many other useful services for mobile development.

Comment: So app center is better than azure? I would like to have a solution which will reduce the platform specific configuration is less. is app center have any pricing like azure?

Comment: Can I configure app center on my backend .net project?'

Comment: It depends what your use case is. App Center pricing is a monthly subscription but there is a free tier which covers push. App Center Push is part of your backend, if you need to call Push from your back end you can use the push rest APIs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/push/rest-api

Answer (score 1):

@groveale App Center Push feature is being retired(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/push/) so I would suggest using firebase or the implementation provided by xamarin docs.